# Question about 物の before a noun

Tags: grammar

I read the definition of the word 報酬:

> 労働や**物の使用**などに対するお礼の金銭や物品

I am a bit unsure if the 物の is the "rentaishi" as jisho list it as, or if the の is making a noun phrase.

I appreciate it if someone could clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this 物 is just "thing(s)", and 物の使用 is "use/consumption of things". 報酬 normally refers to the compensation for services/labor, but maybe someone who wrote this thought 報酬 also refers to the compensation for items used (e.g., 医療材料費 of 診療報酬).

ものの as a rentaishi is usually written in hiragana, and is preceded by a number or such. For example, ものの10分 means "no more than 10 minutes" or "just 10 minutes", and ものの数人 means "only a few people".